# SqlAlchemy drop/create all duplicate relation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using SQL Alchemy and declarative base to define two related tables

```
JiraBase = declarative_base(cls=_Shared)

class JiraSource(JiraBase):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    __tablename__ = 'jira_source'

class JiraProject(JiraBase):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    source = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('jira_source.id'), nullable=False)
    project_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
    project_key = Column(String, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String)

    __table_args__ = (Index('source', 'project_id', 'project_key', unique=True),)
    __tablename__ = 'jira_project'
```

The idea behind the `Index` is that projects are uniquely identified by an `id` and `key` for a given JiraSource.

The tables are being dropped and created via

```
JiraBase.metadata.drop_all(bind=self.engine)
JiraBase.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)
```

This actually drops and creates tables fine; however, also throws an exception

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable) relation "source" already exists

[SQL: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX source ON jira_issue (issue_id)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Thinking somehow because using both a `ForeignKey` and `Index` that both relate to `source`, is this a bad practice or something?  When I comment out the Index entirely or drop the `source` field from it, the error goes away.  Thinking that because I defined `source` as a foreign key that using it again in an index is bad or something?

Any idea why I'm seeing this error?  For now am simply `try/ignoring` in code.

Comment: I don't get that error running the code in the question, using Postgres 10.13, SQLAlchemy 1.3.10, psycopg2 2.8.5.